# Use jQuery in a grid to to make a click event on a button in each row to fetch the value from the text box next to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, grid

I have a grid.  In a each cell in a column in the grid, there is a text box.  Next to each  text box is a button.  Attached to the button is a click event handler (jQuery .click())  What I want to do is when the user clicks the button, I want to fetch the value of the text box immediately next to it.  There are multiple rows in the grid.  Each row how a text box and a button.

I know how to use jQuery to fetch an individual, or group of items (using selectors).  I also know how to attach the click event handler to all the buttons.

But what are some good ways to reference the text box next to the button -- aside from "walking the DOM" (i.e. using .parent() or .next())0

Comment: Could you post your actual HTML mark-up, rather than having us play a logic game to assemble it in our heads? And, incidentally, I think that whatever selector you end up using is going to be a form of 'walking the DOM,' unless you have common attributes between certain (sets of) elements that allow another form attribute-selection to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do it would be to get the TR then find the input from there:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('input');
```

Comment: I like how this one sort of walks the DOM, but uses the queries.  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

You want [.siblings('input')](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) - this will find those input elements "next to the button" that was clicked.